# Neither the success callback nor the error callback is invoked in cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, fingerprint

I want to use the cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio to add fingerprint capability to my app.

The popup telling me that I have to put my finger is well showed.
My fingerprint seems accepted on the screen.

But none of the callback for `Fingerprint.show` are invoked. My code is yet an almost copy/paste of the documentation :

```
function doSubmit() {
  var login = document.getElementById("login")
  var password = document.getElementById("password")

  Fingerprint.isAvailable(isAvailableSuccess, isAvailableError);

  function isAvailableSuccess(result) {

    console.log("Fingerprint available");

    showPopupAuthentication()
  }

  function isAvailableError(message) {
    console.error(message);
  }

}

function showPopupAuthentication() {
  Fingerprint.show({
    clientId: "Fingerprint-Demo",
    clientSecret: "password" //Only necessary for Android
  }, successCallback, errorCallback);

  function successCallback(){
    console.log("Authentication successfull"); // this is not invoked
  }

  function errorCallback(err){
    console.error("Authentication invalid " + err); // neither this one !!
  }
}
```

Do you have a similar behavior?

Cordova CLI 8.0.0
Cordova Android 7.0
cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio 1.3.7

I use an Android 7.0 physical device to test my app.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the fact I use a form and I forgot to prevent default the standard behavior of it.

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <input placeholder="login" name="login" id="login">
    <input placeholder="password" name="password" id="password">
    <button onclick="doSubmit()">OK</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

The callbacks are now invoked.